# vb.net - combobox displays System.Data.DataRowView when trying to select the data from sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I got the System.Data.DataRowView when I tried to select the data from sql database. These are my code:

```
......
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName +' '+ LastName FROM tblVisitor", myConnection)
myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
cboName.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
cboName.DisplayMember = "FirstName"
cboName.DisplayMember = "LastName"
cboName.ValueMember = "FirstName"
cboName.ValueMember = "LastName"
..............
```

and I got the above error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SelectCommand does neither return a column  `LastName` nor `FirstName`. You are only returning one column(a concatenation of both columns).

So this should work:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT VisitorID, LastName, FirstName, (FirstName +' '+ LastName)As FullName FROM tblVisitor", myConnection)
myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
cboName.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
cboName.DisplayMember = "FullName"
cboName.ValueMember = "VisitorID" 'change to the correct pk-column'
```

Comment: since i have 3 combobox bounds to 3 different tables, and after the first combobox is successfully retrieved, the other twos got the error of 'Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ValueMember` as well as `DisplayMember`.

Comment: hey, guy. It does not work either, could u please guide me way?